# You must feed a value for placeholder tensor while using tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am defining an architecture which consists of Batch Normalization implemented in tensorflow.

I am not getting into the entire architecture just showing the relevant part of the issue.

```
self.w3 = tf.layers.Dense(self.hidden_dimension)

// code

h = tf.layers.dropout(tf.layers.batch_normalization(tf.nn.sigmoid(self.w3(x)), 
training = self.is_training, renorm = True), rate = 0.15, training = self.is_training)

// code
```

The official tensorflow implementation for Batch Normalization says 'update ops are placed in tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, so they need to be executed alongside the train_op.'

Now, when I DON'T use

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
self.optimize = tf.group([self.opt, update_ops])
```

The training continues normally WITH NO ERROR. However, I know batch normalization is not being performed here.

But as soon as these two lines are being introduced it gives an unexpected error

```
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor
```

Interestingly, each time I try to execute this function above error keeps changing for different placeholders and does not fix to a particular placeholder. However, I am sure that I have feeding values to all the placeholders (As I already mentioned, training works fine when those two lines are not there).

Just in case you want to see the loss and optimize function

```
with tf.variable_scope(name_or_scope = 'op', reuse = tf.AUTO_REUSE) as scope:
        self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits = self.p_y,
                                                                            labels = self.ans))

        self.optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate)

        gradients, variables = zip(*self.optimizer.compute_gradients(self.cost))
        gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, self.clip_rate)
        self.opt = self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))

        update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
        self.optimize = tf.group([self.opt, update_ops])
```